# Q: react-native init creates a .flowconfig file which requires flow version 0.25.0 but I have flow 0.26.0 installed

Tags: react-native, flowtype

If I tried changing the .flowconfig file to use 0.26.0, flow finds a bunch of errors in the react-native node module. My react-native is version 0.27.2.

Is there a way I can install flow 0.25.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from here. https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases
You can find every release on this page.

You can also install it from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-bin. Just run `npm i flow-bin@0.25`.

I don't however know the way to install previous version of flow from Homebrew.